# How do I formulate this under ZFC set theory?

Tags: algebraic-topology, set-theory

Here is a lemma given in Munkres-Elements of algebraic topology

[image]

This statement seems impossible to be encoded in ZFC set theory. The condition $(a)$ can be formulated in ZFC, but $(b)$ seems impossible to be formulated in ZFC. Could it be encoded in ZFC set theory?

For example, since there is a complete explicit way to construct the singular homology groups of topological spaces, saying "there is a homology functor $H_n:Top\rightarrow Ab$" can be completely formulated in ZFC. However, the condition $(b)$ asserts that there exists a class $\{D_X:X\in Top\}$ such that $D_X$ is natural for all $X$. This cannot be formulated in ZFC. I wonder if there is a smart trick to avoid this size problem.

Comment: Saying that a diagram commutes is just saying that a large number of equalities hold, one for every pair of paths in the diagram that start at the same point and end at the same point. So there is no problem with expressing that in ZFC.

Comment: @CarlMummert The OP's problem is essentially with the map $X\mapsto D_X$, which is a real issue. Since that map isn't a set, we have to argue that it's definable.

Comment: If a commutative diagram depends solely on a single $X$, then there is no problem. But isn't there a problem since this commutative diagram depends on *all* $X$?

Comment: @CarlMummert aha so what you are saying is to write a sentence like "For all $X,Y$, there exists $D_X,D_Y$ each of which satisfying the condition $(a)$, and together they sayisfy $(b)$? Instead of "There *exists* $\{D_X:X\in Top\}$..." ?

Comment: Noah Schweber's answer gets to the heart of the matter, which is that we need a uniform way to define $D_X$ from $X$, and as long as we have that we will be able to formalize this in ZFC. Munkres really is trying to say that there is a map that takes $X$ to $D_X$, such that the map has certain properties; he just says it in a way that hides that map.  In order to  formalize a result like that in ZFC, we need the map to be definable.

Comment: @Rubertos No, that's not enough: we could conceivably have an "unfillable triangle." E.g. we could have three spaces $X, Y, Z$ such that there are $D_X^Y, D_X^Z, D_Y, D_Z$ such that $(D_X^Y, D_Y)$ and $(D_X^Z, D_Z)$ fulfill part (b) for $(X, Y)$ and $(X, Z)$ respectively, but $D_X^Y\not=D_X^Z$. You *really need* to be talking about a definable class function, here; I genuinely don't see a way around that. (Luckily it's not hard to do.)

Comment: The same thing comes up in other settings, by the way. For example, in Peano Arithmetic we may want to prove "For every $a \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a number $2^a$ such that $2^0 = 1$ and $2^{a}2^{b} = 2^{a+b}$ for all $b \in \mathbb{N}$." Because Peano Arithmetic can't quantify over functions, it is somewhat subtle to express this as a theorem, much as the example from Munkres is hard to express in ZFC.

Comment: I actually don't understand the issue. $D_X$ is a function between two groups. This is merely a statement that for every $X$ there is some function $D_X$, and the diagrams commute. Is it impossible to talk about "For every set there is a power set" in the language of set theory? Of course it's possible. Then why is it a problem here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Because the condition (b) that $D_X$ is supposed to satisfy involves the other maps $D_Y$ for arbitrary $Y$.  So it doesn't actually make sense to say that $D_X$ exists for an individual $X$ in isolation; the assertion is that there simultaneously exists $D_X$ for every $X$ such that they are all related to each other in a certain way.

Comment: @Eric: I still don't see how this is necessarily a problem. Sure, it might mean that these $D_X$ maps might not exist (or at least, it's a nontriviliaity condition). But stating it? How is this a problem? But we're treading water here, as Noah gave a good answer to explain this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can be expressed in ZFC. The issue, as you state, is that the "map" $D:X\mapsto D_X$ is a **class function**, since there are proper class-many topological spaces. However, this is fine: the map $D$ is *definable* by a (very messy) formula $\psi$ in the language of set theory, so, rather than writing e.g. "$D_X$ satisfies ...", we can instead write "For every $A$, if $\psi(A, X)$ holds, then $A$ satisfies . . .". (Why is $D$ definable? Look at the proof of the lemma!)

Of course, the general treatment of class maps does go beyond ZFC, either to a *class theory* like $NBG$ or $MK$, or to ZFC augmented with *appropriately large sets*, e.g. ZFC+Universes. But this is unnecessary here, and in most contexts.

Comment: @CarlMummert No, I don't think that's right: we actually need to pick *one specific* $D_X$ for each $X$, since $(b)$ talks about how the various values of $D_X$ relate to each other as $X$ varies across topological spaces. Think by analogy about the statement "For every real $r$ there is a natural number $n_r$ such that $r\ge_Ts$ iff $n_r\ge n_s$ for all reals $s$." This statement is clearly *false*, and this is because the demanded map $n: r\mapsto n_r$ is being forced to meet too many requirements as $r$ varies. The OP's statement is prima facie $\exists^{class}\forall^{set}$.

Comment: I see what you mean.  But as you said, as long as $D_X$ is definable from $X$ then we will be OK.   The phrasing the Munkres uses is not ideal to convey what he is actually proving.

Comment: @CarlMummert Quite right. But I think the OP is also quite right for being worried about this. (And note that it's not enough for $D_X$ to be definable from $X$, for each $X$; we need the definition to be *uniform*.)

Comment: Yes, it's a very good question, particularly because Munkres is probably not focusing at all on how to formalize the result in ZFC. Fortunately, the construction of $D_X$ is entirely uniform and definable from $X$.  (The construction is shown in the image above, and is not any longer in the book.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I still don't get how $D$ can be definable.. Could you please give more details about "For all $A$, if $\psi(A,X)$ holds, then $A$ satisfies..." sentence? Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, the statement of the Lemma in the language "There exists $X\mapsto D_X$ such that..." _cannot_ be formulated in ZFC, since you can't quantify over class functions.  What can be formulated in ZFC is "If you define $X\mapsto D_X$ as specified in the proof below, then it satisfies...".

Comment: @Rubertos Here's an example. Consider the sentence $\varphi=$"For every set $a$, there is a set $b_a$ such that $a\in b_a$." On the face of things, $\varphi$ asserts the existence of a class function $a\mapsto b_a$ with a certain property. However, there's a clear *definable* class function which behaves this way: the map $a\mapsto\{a\}$. Consider the formula $\psi(x, y)=\forall z(z\in y\iff z=x)$; we can prove in ZFC that for every $x$ there is a unique $y$ satisfying $\psi(x, y)$, so $\psi$ defines a class function $F$ from sets to sets which sends $x$ to the unique $y$ with $\psi(x, y)$.

Comment: @Rubertos (cont'd) Moreover, consider the sentence $\varphi'=$"For every set $a$, $a\in F(a)$" - or better, "$\forall a\forall b(\psi(a, b)\implies a\in b)$". This is expressible and provable in ZFC, and is clearly *stronger* than the original $\varphi$. This is what I'm talking about: we take a sentence in the language of class theory, and replace it with a stronger sentence in the language of set theory which we can also prove.